# SP3 can't seem to get screen size in C#?

Tags: c#, screen, windows-8.1, tablet

I've been working on a simple application to retrieve screenshots on Windows. The code I have works great on everything but a Surface Pro. I can't seem to retrieve the screen dimensions dynamically and it seems stuck on giving me a 1420x968 working area no matter what.

```
Rectangle bounds = this.Bounds; //SP3 dimensions new Rectangle(0, 0, 2160, 1440);

using (Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(bounds.Width, bounds.Height))
{
    using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(new Point(bounds.Left, bounds.Top), Point.Empty, bounds.Size);
    }
    bitmap.Save(dirToUse + accessionNumber + ".jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the code for `this.Bounds` or `bounds`, we can't see the problem code.

Comment: this.Bounds = the forms bounds. Should have clarified this is a windows forms app with 1 form and 1 control, the webbrowser control.

Comment: If you want screen size, ask for it, `Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds`  I don't have Windows 8 to test with.  Your code is asking for the size for the form.

Comment: On Windows 8, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds returns the same as this.Bounds when the form is maximized. The code posted, as well as your comment work great on everything up to Windows 8.1

Comment: I'll go out on a limb and say there's some scaling going on.  Again, I don't have Windows 8 available to me, but that's all I can guess.

Comment: I'll agree with you and still trying to figure out how to compensate for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try telling Windows your application is DPI aware in the manifest file.

```
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns:asmv3="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3" >
   <asmv3:application>
        <asmv3:windowsSettings xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SMI/2005/WindowsSettings">
             <dpiAware>true</dpiAware>
        </asmv3:windowsSettings>
   </asmv3:application>
</assembly>
```

More [here](http://blogs.telerik.com/winformsteam/posts/14-02-11/winforms-scaling-at-large-dpi-settings-is-it-even-possible-).